# What is the purpose of __str__ and __repr__?

Tags: python

I really don't understand where are `__str__` and `__repr__` used in Python. I mean, I get that `__str__` returns the string representation of an object. But why would I need that? In what use case scenario? Also, I read about the usage of `__repr__`

But what I don't understand is, where would I use them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python

Comment: For anyone coming from Ruby, the tl;dr is: `__str__` = `to_s` and `__repr__` = `inspect`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between \_\_str\_\_ and \_\_repr\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

[`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

> Called by the `repr()` built-in function and by string conversions (reverse quotes) to compute the "official" string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment).

[`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

> Called by the `str()` built-in function and by the print statement to compute the "informal" string representation of an object.

Use `__str__` if you have a class, and you'll want an informative/informal output, whenever you use this object as part of string. E.g. you can define `__str__` methods for Django models, which then gets rendered in the Django administration interface. Instead of something like `<Model object>` you'll get like first and last name of a person, the name and date of an event, etc.

---

`__repr__` and `__str__` are similar, in fact sometimes equal (Example from `BaseSet` class in `sets.py` from the standard library):

```
def __repr__(self):
    """Return string representation of a set.

    This looks like 'Set([<list of elements>])'.
    """
    return self._repr()

# __str__ is the same as __repr__
__str__ = __repr__
```

Comment: what ` return self._repr()` does, when I run the code and try to understand it say __repr__() takes exactly one argument.

Comment: So, can I use `__repr__` instead of `__str__` django?

Answer (score 69):

The one place where you use them both a lot is in an interactive session. If you print an object then its `__str__` method will get called, whereas if you just use an object by itself then its `__repr__` is shown:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = Decimal(1.25)
>>> print(a)
1.25                  <---- this is from __str__
>>> a
Decimal('1.25')       <---- this is from __repr__
```

The `__str__` is intended to be as human-readable as possible, whereas the `__repr__` should aim to be something that could be used to recreate the object, although it often won't be exactly how it was created, as in this case.

It's also not unusual for both `__str__` and `__repr__` to return the same value (certainly for built-in types).

Comment: Thanks for the example, gave me a better understanding of where this gets used by default

Answer (score 18):

Building up and on the previous answers and showing some more examples. If used properly, the difference between `str` and `repr` is clear. In short `repr` should return a string that can be copy-pasted to rebuilt the exact state of the object, whereas `str` is useful for `logging` and `observing` debugging results. Here are some examples to see the different outputs for some known libraries.

## Datetime

```
print repr(datetime.now())    #datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 12, 18, 49, 27, 134411)
print str(datetime.now())     #2017-12-12 18:49:27.134452
```

The `str` is good to print into a log file, where as `repr` can be re-purposed if you want to run it directly or dump it as commands into a file.

```
x = datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 12, 18, 49, 27, 134411)
```

## Numpy

```
print repr(np.array([1,2,3,4,5])) #array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print str(np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))  #[1 2 3 4 5]
```

in Numpy the `repr` is again directly consumable.

## Custom Vector3 example

```
class Vector3(object):
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.x = args[0]
        self.y = args[1]
        self.z = args[2]

    def __str__(self):
        return "x: {0}, y: {1}, z: {2}".format(self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Vector3([{0},{1},{2}])".format(self.x, self.y, self.z)
```

In this example, `repr` returns again a string that can be directly consumed/executed, whereas `str` is more useful as a debug output.

```
v = Vector3([1,2,3])
print str(v)     #x: 1, y: 2, z: 3
print repr(v)    #Vector3([1,2,3])
```

> One thing to keep in mind, if `str` isn't defined but `repr`, `str` will automatically call `repr`. So, it's always good to at least define `repr`

Answer (score 17):

Grasshopper, when in doubt [go to the mountain](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+__repr__) and [read the Ancient Texts](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__). In them you will find that __repr__() should:

> If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value.

Comment: -1 as this doesn't even attempt to answer the actual question, which is what the use cases are.

Comment: @Scott: You are correct. But then again the *actual question* showed absolutely no attempt to go to the primary docs in the first place. It's one thing to ask a question that shows you've made an attempt to answer it for yourself but are still a little confused about some aspect of it, and another thing altogether to post a question like this. Just typing in his subject line as a new question shows that 5 of the top 6 suggested SO threads would have answered his question, but he couldn't be bothered. I did not quite give him a lmgtfy answer, but I was sorely tempted.

Comment: Actually he did say that he'd read about `__repr__`, the official docs don't really answer the question as to why you'd use it, and just because a question is answered elsewhere isn't a good reason for it not also to be answered on SO (as often as not Googling will bring you back here!) If you don't think that the question is worth answering then you could just not answer it, though in this case I do agree that it's covered very well already on SO and so linking to duplicates would be an appropriate response.

Comment: Actually, you are incorrect. The docs explicitly say why you would use it, to wit: "This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the representation is information-rich and unambiguous." I've seen too many forums (fora?) sink under the weight of Help Vampires and it pains me to see it starting to come to pass on SO. As for linking to the other obvious SO answers, that's the whole purpose of the suggestion mechanism that kicks in when you are typing in your Subject line, yet he chose to ignore all of the suggestions. QED & PDQ, too.

Comment: Well the docs still don't say *how* to use it for debugging, but I really didn't intend to get into an argument over this. We at least agree that your answer didn't address the question, so my -1 still feels justified to me. If a question is poorly written/a duplicate/trivial then you can help to improve the question, link to duplicates, or simply down-vote the question. I think my main objection here is that answers should try to answer the question - there are other mechanisms for criticising the question. I'll shut up now as I think we both have better things to do here.

Answer (score 7):

Lets have a class without `__str__` function.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first 
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay

emp1 = Employee('Ivan', 'Smith', 90000)

print(emp1)
```

When we print this instance of the class, `emp1`, this is what we get:

```
<__main__.Employee object at 0x7ff6fc0a0e48>
```

This is not very helpful, and certainly this is not what we want printed if we are using it to display (like in html)

So now, the same class, but with `__str__` function:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first 
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay

    def __str__(self):
        return(f"The employee {self.first} {self.last} earns {self.pay}.")
        # you can edit this and use any attributes of the class

emp2 = Employee('John', 'Williams', 90000)

print(emp2)
```

Now instead of printing that there is an object, we get what we specified with return of `__str__` function:

`The employee John Williams earns 90000`

Answer (score 3):

`str` will be informal and readable format whereas `repr` will give official object representation.

```
class Complex:
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, real, imag):
        self.real = real
        self.imag = imag

    # "official" string representation of an object
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Rational(%s, %s)' % (self.real, self.imag)

    # "informal" string representation of an object (readable)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s + i%s' % (self.real, self.imag)

    t = Complex(10, 20)

    print (t)     # this is usual way we print the object
    print (str(t))  # this is str representation of object 
    print (repr(t))  # this is repr representation of object   

Answers : 

Rational(10, 20) # usual representation
10 + i20      # str representation
Rational(10, 20)  # repr representation
```

Answer (score 1):

**str** and **repr** are both ways to represent. You can use them when you are writing a class.

```
class Fraction:
def __init__(self, n, d):
    self.n = n
    self.d = d
def __repr__(self):
    return "{}/{}".format(self.n, self.d)
```

for example when I print a instance of it, it returns things.

```
print(Fraction(1, 2))
```

results in

```
1/2
```

while

```
class Fraction:
def __init__(self, n, d):
    self.n = n
    self.d = d
def __str__(self):
    return "{}/{}".format(self.n, self.d)
print(Fraction(1, 2))
```

also results in

```
1/2
```

But what if you write both of them, which one does python use?

```
class Fraction:
def __init__(self, n, d):
    self.n = n
    self.d = d
def __str__(self):
    return "str"
def __repr__(self):
    return "repr"

print(Fraction(None, None))
```

This results in

```
str
```

So python actually uses the **str** method not the **repr** method when both are written.

Comment: I think there is no reason to have two methods returning (almost) the same information. The repr string would be better "Fraction(n, d)", IMHO. Check the official documentation for repr method.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a class and wish to inspect an instance, you see the print doesn't give much useful information

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


p1 = Person("John", 36)
print(p1)  # <__main__.Animal object at 0x7f9060250410>
```

Now see a class with a **str**, it shows the instance information and with **repr** you even don't need the print. Nice no?

```py
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, color, age, breed):
        self.color = color
        self.age = age
        self.breed = breed

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.color} {self.breed} of age {self.age}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"repr : {self.color} {self.breed} of age {self.age}"


a1 = Animal("Red", 36, "Dog")
a1  # repr : Red Dog of age 36
print(a1)  # Red Dog of age 36
```

Comment: This is a bad example of repr in this case. The correct (reasonable) string should be 'Animal("Red", 36, "Dog")'. It allows one to reconstruct the object. "repr  :" adds no value to the printed string representation. Just an arbitrary useless constant, sorry.