# Using __str__ in a special way

Tags: python, latex

I'm trying to generate LaTeX documents using Python. I'm using classes for separate types of content and they eventually need to be converted to a string in the document that can be compiled by LaTeX. Would `__str__` be the right function for this, or is that for more consise summary of the class and should I use something like `.render` in this case?

The main reason I'm confused is that most objects don't have being converted to a string as an end goal.

This is an example class for a package line. Keep in mind the whole document is also a class that would have the same implementation to be converted to a string.

```
class Package:

    """A class that represents a package"""

    def __init__(self, name, option=None):
        self.name = name
        self.option = option

    def __str__(self):
        if self.option is None:
            option = ''
        else:
            option = '[' + self.option + ']'

        return r'\usepackage' + option + '{' + self.name + '}\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **str** method is supposed to "a string containing a nicely printable representation of an object" (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str ). I'd say formatting commands do not fit in there (even though the end goal when using LaTeX usually is to get something nicely printable), and that a `render` method, as you suggest, is more appropriate.

The down-side is that simple string concatenation using `+` will then not do the formatting for you - but on the other hand, "explicit is better than implicit" is part of the Zen of Python (see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ ).

Comment: The thing that is the most annoying thing is that I can't simply interchange actual strings and my special classes, since I sometimes have to call a method.

Answer (score 0):

This a design question and depens of how large and extensible your project will be. You can find a nice explanation of the **str** method here: [What is the purpose of __str__ and __repr__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691101/what-is-the-purpose-of-str-and-repr-in-python)

If you only want to generate Latex and say write it to STDOUT then is valid. If you want a more flexible implementation (say instead of Latex you want Markdown) I would give the responsability to another class that knows how to process each type depending of the output. (That'd be a more Java-ish approach)

```
class LatexContentRender:

     def render(content_item):
         # do stuff and get the important 
         # components from the content_item
```