# How to stop the Counter function printing the actual world 'counter'?

Tags: python, function, printing, counter

I am trying to create a piece of coding which counts how many times each vowel is used in a sentence. My current coding looks like:

```
sentence = str(input("Please enter your line of text; ").lower())
only_vowels = re.sub(r"[^aeiou]", "", sentence)

c = (collections.Counter(list(only_vowels)))

print(c)
```

However, when I print enter the sentence as "Hello World"....and the coding tries to print 'c', it returns...

```
Counter({'o': 2, 'e': 1})
```

Of course, it has done its job and counted how many times each vowel occurred... However, I do not want the word 'Counter' to be printed at the front each time. Is there any way I can stop this?!

Comment: `print` can prints only text so it converts `Counter` object to text before it prints it. If you don't like it then convert `Counter` to text on your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> c = dict(Counter({'o':2, 'e': 1}))
>>> c
{'o': 2, 'e': 1}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's printing "Counter" because that's what the Counter object is designed to do when you request it in [string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691101/what-is-the-purpose-of-str-and-repr-in-python). what you want is the dictionary inside of counter. To do this, you want to convert it to a dict object. This can be done by doing:

```
print dict(Counter({'o':2, 'e': 1}))
```