# I am creating a class in which I want to reverse a list preferably in place

Tags: python-3.x

## I keep getting the error "<**main**.reverse object at 0x000001C1E1EAE9E8>"

```
class reverse:
    def __init__(self, list1):
        self.list1 = list(reversed(list1))

i = reverse([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
print(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not "an error". This is just the default representation of objects that do not implement `__str__`.

You may want to implement it, ie

```
class reverse:
    def __init__(self, list1):
        self.list1 = list(reversed(list1))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.list1)
```

See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691101/what-is-the-purpose-of-str-and-repr).

Comment: So I needed to convert it to a string.

Comment: @FakhrAli No. When you simply print an object, it is already implicitly converted to a string. But it's your responsability, as the implementer  of a new class, to define (by the `__str__` method) how this conversion is going to happen.